# TinyMCE forecolorpicker backcolorpicker addon to the bar

Tags: html, plugins, tinymce, wysiwyg

As you can see in: [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x%3aButtons/controls) theres "forecolorpicker backcolorpicker" but when i add them as the following code they do nothing and i cant find a plugin to add:

```
    tinymce.init({
    selector: ".editableText",
    inline: true,
    menubar: false,
    toolbar_items_size: 'small',
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link directionality textcolor visualblocks paste",
        " ",
        ""
    ],
    toolbar: "forecolorpicker backcolorpicker"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this

```
toolbar: "forecolor backcolor"
```

Otherwise tinymce won't be able to add the buttons.